# Make linear layout scrollable when keyboard opens

Tags: android

There is a screen with a fixed header(`AppBarLayout`) and `LinearLayout`(with four `TextView's` and a `Button` at bottom). When keyboard is opened text field gets hidden. I want only linear layout to be scrollable. Have tried with `ScrollView`, `adjustResize` in `manifest` & i am not using

```
"Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Nothing worked out. How to achieve the same.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a minimal code sample?

Comment: put your linearLayout in scrollView simple is that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to push the layout up when keyboard is shown.

```
getActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: This solution will push complete screen up. The header should remain fixed.